# Dynamically reference Firestore Document

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a quiz-like eLearning project with a CMS behind it.
I have the CMS form writing to a specific collection in my firestore, however, I want to be able to add a question to more than one course.
My CMS form has a dropdown,  where the admin can select what course they would like to add the question to. However, i'm not quite sure how I would then transfer that over into my actions which adds the question to the course.

**Add.js (CMS Form)**

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import './add.css'
import { createQuestion } from '../../store/actions/questionActions'
import { connect } from 'react-redux' 

class add extends Component {

    state = {
        course: 'TestCourse1',
        question: '',
        questionType: 'MultipleChoice',
        correctAnswer: '',
        wrongAnswer: '',
        wrongAnswer2: '',
        wrongAnswer3: '',
        courses: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let db = firebase.firestore()

        db.collection('courses').get().then(snapshot => {
            const courses = []
            snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
                const data = doc.data()
                courses.push(data)
                console.log(courses)
            })
            this.setState({courses})
        }).catch(error => { console.error(error) })
    }


    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
        [e.target.id]: e.target.value,
        }) 
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // console.log(this.state)
        this.props.createQuestion(this.state)
    }



    render() {

        const {courses} = this.state
        return (
            <div className = "Container">
            <div className = "AddQuestion">
               <h1> Add a question </h1>
               <div className = "AddQuestionFormContainer">
                <form>

                    <label htmlFor = "courses"> Courses</label>  <br/>
                    <select name = "course" id = "course" onChange = {this.handleChange} value = {this.state.course}>
                    {
                        courses.length && courses.map(course => {
                            return <option value = {course.courseName} key = {course.courseName}> {course.courseName}</option>
                        })

                    }
                    </select> <br/><br/>

                    <label  htmlFor = "question"> Question </label>  <br/>
                    <input type = "text" id = "question" placeholder = "Enter your question" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                    <br/><br/>

                    <label  htmlFor = "question"> Question Type </label><br/>
                    <select name = "questionType" id = "questionType" onChange={this.handleChange} value = {this.state.questionType}  >
                        <option value = "MultipleChoice" > Multiple Choice</option>
                        <option value = "TrueOrFalse"> True or False </option>
                    </select>
                    <br/><br/>

                    <label  htmlFor = "correctAnswer"> Correct Answer</label> <br/>
                    <input type = "text" id = "correctAnswer" placeholder = "Correct Answer" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                    <br/><br/>
                    <label  htmlFor = "wrongAnswer"> Wrong Answers </label><br/>
                    <input type = "text" id = "wrongAnswer" placeholder = "Wrong Answer" onChange={this.handleChange} /><br/>
                    <input type = "text" id = "wrongAnswer2" placeholder = "Wrong Answer" onChange={this.handleChange} /><br/>
                    <input type = "text" id = "wrongAnswer3" placeholder = "Wrong Answer" onChange={this.handleChange} /><br/> <br/> 

                    <button onClick = {this.handleSubmit}> Submit </button>





                </form>
               </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        createQuestion: (question) => dispatch(createQuestion(question))
    }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(add)
```

**questionActions.js (which adds to the DB collection)**

```
export const createQuestion = (question) =>{
    return(dispatch, getState, { getFirestore, getFirebase }) => {
        firestore.collection('courses').doc('testcourse1').collection('questions').add({
            ...question
        }).then(()=>{
        dispatch({type: 'CREATE_QUESTION', question});
        }).catch((err)=>{
            dispatch({type: 'CREATE_QUESTION_ERROR', err})
        })
    }
};
```

Basically, I need to be able to make the

```
 firestore.collection('courses').doc('testcourse1').collection('questions').add({...})
```

Dynamic and read the middle doc ('testcourse1') from the value set in the dropdown menu.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you either:

1. need a second parameter to your `createQuestion` function that takes the `id` of the selected question from the dropdown. So the method would look like `export const createQuestion = (question, questionID) => ...`
2. since it looks like the new document ID is basically the same as the state's `course` key's value (`testcourse1` vs `TestCourse1`), you could dynamically create the doc ID by just calling it `question.course.toLowerCase()` in which case the firestore `.add()` would be:

```js
...
export const createQuestion = (question) =>{
  return(dispatch, getState, { getFirestore, getFirebase }) => {
    const docID = question.course.toLowerCase() // transform TestCourse1 to testcourse1
    firestore
      .collection('courses')
      .doc(docID)
      .collection('questions')
      .add({
        ...question
       })
...
};
```